# php is creating sessions automatically with [session.auto_start=0]

Tags: php, apache, debian

Php is creating sessions automatically, yet "session.auto_start" is turned "off"

Any ideas to what may be causing this ?

Here is an example with just phpinfo()

(this is in a directory with no dynamic content aside this file)

Simply open chrome developer tools, and you can see that a session is being created despite the option being turned off

https://hub.maserdigital.com/info.php

[image]